# Integrating C/C++ code in Xamarin for iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Under Visual Studio 2015, I have integrated Android C++ code into Xamarin and it works as expected. Now, I am trying to do the same for iOS and am running into some basic issues.

I am assuming the integration mechanism is the same for iOS as that of Android in the sense that a shared library (probably .so) is created that one can load using `DllImport` in C# code.

When I try to add a new C++ project for iOS to my solution, the only option that seems to make sense is Visual C++-->Cross Platform-->iOS-->Shared Library. I added this project type as `MyTestShared`. This actually ends up creating three projects - `MyTestShared.Shared, MyTestShared.iOS, and MyTestShared.Android`. Project `MyTestShared.iOS` already has an external method defined as `char* iOSInfo()`. However, when I try to add project `MyTestShared.iOS` as a reference to my `MyMainApp.iOS` project, I see an error "A reference to MyTestShared.iOS could not be added. An assembly must have a dll or exe extension."

Questions:

1. For Android C++, it generates exactly one project. Why does it create three projects for iOS C++?
2. How do I add a reference to MyTestShared.iOS? What is it that I am missing?
3. I see there is an option to create a static C++ library for iOS. Can I reference it somehow in my C# code?

Regards.